# Отслеживание времени теста Codeception

Tags: php, test-automation, codeception

Доброго дня.

Речь идет о приемочных тестах. 
В описании теста стоит условие, например, время прохождения теста не более 15 секунд.

Есть какой нибудь метод которым можно получить времени теста (именно единичного) чтобы далее писать его куда-нибудь в лог для дальнейшего анализа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отслеживания процесса выполнения тестов Codeception предоставляет мощный механизм *Расширений* ([*Extensions*](http://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#Extension)). Вы можете определить собственное расширение, которое получает время теста после его выполнения и сохраняет эту величину там, где вам нужно.

Для примера приведу код расширения, которое выводит в консоль путь выполненного тестового сценария и время его выполнения.

**tests/_support/TimingExtension.php**:

```
<?php

class TimingExtension extends \Codeception\Extension
{
    public static $events = array(
        'test.after' => 'afterTest',
    );

    public function afterTest(\Codeception\Event\TestEvent $e)
    {
        echo(sprintf(
            "%s: %s\n",
            $e->getTest()->getMetadata()->getFilename(),
            $e->getTime()
        ));
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы это расширение заработало, вам нужно подключить его в секции `extensions` основного конфигурационного файла Codeception (`codeception.yml`).

**tests/codeception.yml**:

```
# ...
extensions:
    enabled:
        - TimingExtension
        # Прочие расширения, которые уже были здесь
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
# ...
```

Подробнее о подключении собственных расширений можно почитать в [документации](http://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#Enabling-Extension).

Comment: Спасибо Дмитрий!